# How to reverse the pinout of connector in Eagle

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad

I have a screw connector with multiple pins and it seems like it will be easier to do the layout if I reverse the pinout on the connector. So if I have a 3 pin screw connector I would just need to switch pin 1 with pin 3 in the layout.  Is there a way to do that? Or do I just need to update my schematic to do it the other way?

Comment: You could presumably delete or disconnect the existing connector, mirror the schematic symbol vertically, and put it back in the same place in the drawing.  That will likely force you to re-route any traces, but you probably couldn't complete those anyway.  For only three pins, just reversing the schematic wires may be preferable, or of course you can use labelled nets.

Answer (score 1):

The schematic should always reflect the layout. So you have to either change the schematic directly, or back-annotate from the layout.